# What is the need for input and output iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

All standard containers support at least forward iterator types.If this is the case then what is the need for input and output iterators?

Comment: Are _input_ and _output_ iterator types (traits)?

Answer (score 2):

Stream iterators are pure input or output iterators.

Comment: Thanks now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms operate on sequences of values that are delineated by iterators; that's the key abstraction in the STL. Algorithms don't care where the iterators came from; they just care about the operations that are defined for iterators.

Containers are one way of managing a sequence of values to provide iterators, but they are not the only way. In particular, file operations are typically not done with containers, but through iterators such as `std::istream_iterator` (an input iterator) and `std::ostream_iterator` (an output iterator).

Answer (score 0):

> All standard containers support at least forward iterator types.If this is the case then what is the need for input and output iterators?

These things are orthogonal. A *forward iterator* restricts an iterator type to certain operations applied to it.

*Input* and *output* iterators are used as parameters in copy and transformation operations applied to containers (and result in the corresponding *output container*). They can be *forward iterators* or other types that allow the necessary operations.

Comment: Ok you are right but my question is is there any cotainer which return Input or Output iterator?  If i use copy on vector i am passing the random_access_iterator(Although it have all the functionality of Input or Output operator).

Comment: @user1438832 I still don't get you concern. A container allows you to get _iterators_ for it. If these are used for input or output relates to the transformation function used.